# Should I (always) use a comma before 'too' when it is at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

For example:
Robots are of great help to human's development, and might be of great importance in the future, too.

Q1. Is the comma before 'too' necessary in the above sentence?

Q2. Should I (always) use a comma before 'too' when it is at the end of a sentence?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would *never* put a comma before "too" like that. To me, a comma 'detaches' the rest of the sentence from what comes before it, and here the "too" should be firmly 'attached' to what comes before! Otherwise it is left dangling...

Often when people read something aloud and put a pause in the middle of the sentence, they have an urge to put a comma there. While often this is correct, it's not always - and not in this case.